# Primefaces p:captcha --> if given input is wrong/empty I've got a malformedXML error

Tags: jsf, primefaces, captcha

I have written a jsf2 (cdi) web-application, using jQuery, a syntaxhighlighting script lib. On one page I'm using the primefaces 3.2 p:captcha component.

here is the snippet, where using the captcha component.

> ```
>           <p>
>                 <p:captcha
>                     id="commentCaptcha"
>                     theme="white"
>                     required="true"
>                     requiredMessage="Bitte geben Sie die angezeigten Zeichen im Captcha Dialog ein."                        
>                     validatorMessage="Die Captcha Prüfung ist fehlgeschlagen. Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut."
>                     secure="true"
>                     language="de"/>
>             </p>  
>             <p>
>                 <h:commandButton
>                     action="#{commentCreatorBean.createCommentForArticle(newComment, article)}" 
>                     value="Eintragen">
>                     <f:ajax 
>                         execute="commentCaptcha name mail comment" 
>                         render=":commentsGroup @form :commentMessages"/>                        
>                 </h:commandButton>
>                 <div id="hint">...</div>
>             </p>
> ```

- If the given input in the captcha dialog is correct, then everything work's fine and in this case a comment is persisted.
- Is the given input empty, than the requiredMessage is shown in the h:messages area and a pop-up show's an error msg (see the error msg's below)
- Is the given input wrong, than the validatorMessage is shown in the h:messages area and also a pop-up show's an error msg (see the error msg's below)

If using the chromium browser, I've got the error message: **malformedXML: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101**
If using the firefox browser, I've got: **malformedXML: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)**

Does anybody know, what the problem is? I'm registered at google's recaptcha page with my domain. The public and private key are set in the web.xml ( followed the instruction's of primefaces docu )

Thank's in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question and include the raw XML response. So far now I *guess* that it has got something to do with that `ü` character.

Comment: Thank's for your comment. But I'm not really sure, what do you mean with "raw XML response"? Do you mean the response from the recaptcha service? Sorry. Btw. I have removed *ü* of the validatorMessage attribute. The same error occurr's.

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome/Firebug, go to the *Net(work)* tab, send the ajax request, then explore the request details, you should see the raw XML response in there.

Comment: Ok. I have understand. I will give it a try and answer/edit again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to submit the Primefaces Captcha via AJAX.

This won't work.

The Primefaces Captcha is an extension of the Recaptcha plugin and it currently does not support AJAX functionality.

Comment: Hi, I've found following post http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6991 There someone has used the p:commandButton with the oncomplete="Recaptcha.reload()" call. I will check this. But first I have to look, how the primefaces commandButton work's. I don't think, that I can use the f:ajax element as a child element of the primefaces button?! Or is it possible? Is the process attr of p:commandButton == execute attr of f:ajax and the update attr of p:commandButton == render attr of f:ajax?